# How does Matlab calculate the solution of underdetermined systems?

Tags: r, matlab

For solving rectangular linear systems `Ax=b`, where `A` is `m`x`n` and `n>m`, Matlab performs first a QR factorization then solves a triangular linear system by substitution. For example:
if `A` is a 4x6 matrix:

```
A =

    0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324    0.0975
    0.2785    0.5469    0.9575    0.9649    0.1576    0.9706
    0.9572    0.4854    0.8003    0.1419    0.4218    0.9157
    0.7922    0.9595    0.6557    0.0357    0.8491    0.9340
```

and

```
b=

   -0.9661
    0.1590
   -0.0391
   -0.2491
```

to solve `Ax=b` we simply do:

```
x=A\b;
```

and the solution is:

```
x =

   -0.4284
   -0.6475
         0
   -0.1153
         0
    0.7662
```

The underlying steps in this computation are:

1. QR decomposition of `A`, then `Ax=b`would be equivalent to `Q*R*x=b`.
2. As `inv(Q)=Q'`and `R` is upper triangular, solving the system would return to solving `R*x=b1` where `b1=Q'*b`.

As `R` is upper triangular of size 6x4, we have to perform a back-substitution. How does Matlab perform the back substitution knowing that `R` is not square?

I'm porting this computation to C and have succesfully done it until `R*x=b1`, I'm lost with the back substitution and I want to find the same result as Matlab.

**Edit:**
For the above matrix `A`:
Solving `Ax=b`is equivalent to solving `Rx=b1`where:

```
R =

   -1.5117   -1.3991   -1.0952   -0.7786   -1.0819   -1.3007
         0   -0.5641   -0.2197   -0.6538   -0.2920   -0.2481
         0         0   -0.8692   -0.2077    0.1422   -0.9295
         0         0         0   -0.8426    0.2182    0.2125
```

and

```
b1 =

   -0.9661
    0.1590
   -0.0391
   -0.2491
```

This system is solved by back-substitution as `R` is upper triangular, this is straightforward in case of square triangular matrices (i.e `m=n`), However, `R` is not square. How does Matlab perform the back-substitution to find `x`?

Comment: The [**documentation**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) is quite clear and extensive. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: OP, unless it's an academic exercice may I suggest using a library to do this operation? there are numerous well tested and optimised libraries that solves this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How MATLAB implements in details the under-determined case only Mathworks know! But a way you can do it is as follow.

```
A*x = b
A' = Q*R
```

Now if you look at R you will have something of the form

```
R = [R1; zeros]
```

where R1 is square.

you can express the solution as:

```
x = Q * [inv(R1')*b; zeros]
```

as you indicates that you already solved the problem of inverting a square matrix that should be easy :)

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not 100% sure what MATLAB does, but I can tell you the following:

For your underdetermined matrix A (nxm), we can take A' = QR. We also see that A = R'Q'. Note that now, R has n nonzero rows.  We can then solve the system by recognizing R'Q'x=b, then Q'x=inv(R')*b. The RHS can be solved by back-substitution, we'll call it y. So Q'x=y. But Q is self-Hermitian, so x=Qy. And there you have the least squares solution.

Doing this in MATLAB we get:

```
>> [Q,R] = qr(A')

Q =

   -0.4918    0.2143   -0.6131   -0.5675   -0.1086    0.0503
   -0.5468    0.0638    0.0596    0.5238   -0.5922   -0.2614
   -0.0767   -0.6389   -0.1919   -0.0733    0.2275   -0.7014
   -0.5514   -0.2397    0.6743   -0.3550    0.1568    0.1821
   -0.3818    0.2094   -0.1834    0.4750    0.7368    0.0904
   -0.0589   -0.6637   -0.3090    0.2158   -0.1351    0.6291


R =

   -1.6565   -1.1588   -1.0907   -1.3634
         0   -1.3597   -0.8286   -0.6385
         0         0   -0.9760   -0.9745
         0         0         0    0.5972
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0

>> Q*(R'\b)

ans =

   -0.4256
   -0.3057
    0.3568
   -0.2745
   -0.2823
    0.4249

>>
```

I used backslash above for R'\b, but it's clear you can back-substitute in your own routine.

We can verify this by computing the solution using the pseudo-inverse of A:

```
>> A'*inv(A*A')*b

ans =

   -0.4256
   -0.3057
    0.3568
   -0.2745
   -0.2823
    0.4249
```

You can easily check that this is a valid solution of course. This should be readily implementable in C.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, the trick then is to do `QR(A')` instead of `QR(A)`..It is true that an underdetermined system has infinity of solutions..I'll use the solution you gave in my C code even it is different from the one returned by matlab..In the documentation, it is mentioned that Matlab returns the sparsest solution..but it seems that how to compute it is a secret of Mathworks :)